# How can I store a variable into URL to PHP page?

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, url

I have a link. When I send this link to someone the link will be : `xxxx.com/?code=varname`.

When I send the link to another people the link will be changed e.g. `xxxx.com/?code=varname2`

When I send the link to another people the link will be changed e.g. `xxxx.com/?code=varname3`, etc.

I want to save all this links in one PHP page like this: `site.com/vars.php`. I want to store the code after `code=`.

How can I do that?

My PHP index contains this code: `print_r($_GET);`, but when I open this index.php the result will be: `Array ( )`.

Answer (score 0):

urldemo.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageRedirect(value)
        {
            alert(value);
            window.location=value;
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <form>
        <select onchange="pageRedirect(this.value)">
            <option>select.php/?code=abc</option>
            <option>arraydemo.php/?code=xyz</option>
            <option>redirect.php/?code=paresh</option>
        </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

redirect.php

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['code'];
?>
```

Comment: Admittedly the question is rather poor, but this answer doesn't give any explanation of its solution. Can you expand on the code you have offered?